# Please implement an undo-button in the edit-modus

Tags: feature-request, edits, android-app

As I am more and more using the app to look on the Stack Exchange sites, and therefore am editing more and more questions or answers with the app, I am also getting more and more frustrated by the lack of an `undo` button in the `edit` modus.

You see, when editing a question or answer on a computer with a remote keyboard, one can easily press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to undo the (most recent) changes. However, on mobile devices (particularly Android devices in this case) this is not the case.

At that it's also impossible to see the original asked question whilst editing, due to which it gets quite annoying when somebody accidentally deletes a sentence, does not remember the (exact) wording and wants it back: when having made a lot of changes already, simply going back to the question and forth to editing is quite a pain.

Therefore, I would like to have an `undo` button in the editing mode of the Android-app.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> also works on SE Android app on some devices (at least on my Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1; **your mileage may vary**): it will undo the last operation.

It can be achieved in 2 ways:

1. Use external (e.g. Bluetooth) keyboard
2. Use [Hacker's Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard) that has <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (and other possibly useful) keys.

This is only a workaround until the `undo` button is implemented.

Comment: I use option 2 and Ctrl + Z does not work for me (Note 2, Android 4.4.4). As for option 1: I prefer a software solution over hardware.

Comment: I agree with your premise; external hardware is troublesome, and 3rd-party solution doesn't always work. I just put this as an answer if they are okay with workaround.