# Update code formatting warning on Android

Tags: bug, android-app

While editing some question with code (which is a hell on the app, btw), I got this warning:

> [image: which ctrl+k?]

This is the exact same warning as when on a desktop computer, and we have the `code`-button, but we have no  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  button (as I also stated in my [previous question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272229/311345))!
Neither is there a `[?]`-icon on the toolbar.

In case anyone ever would do something about the app again, please fix this misleading "help"-message.

Comment: As stated on my answer on your previous question, there's a keyboard app with Ctrl key. However, it doesn't work in this case, so I fully agree to make the message present the actual state.